# Is it possible to sign my data using SSH private key in perl?

Tags: perl, ssh, sign

I am new to perl so this might be very basic, but i am finding no way around this problem. I am trying to sign my data which has to be send over https connection using my `ssh private key(id_rsa)`. I am not able to do so using perl and i am at it for days. Please someone show me a possible way to do so. If any more info is needed please ask me. Thanks in advance

My code as asked is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Slurp   qw(read_file);
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 encode_base64 );

my $keystring = read_file( 'id_rsa' );
my $privatekey = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($keystring);
$privatekey->use_pkcs1_padding();
my $datatosign = "hello";
my $signature = $privatekey->sign($datatosign);
my $base64 = encode_base64($signature);
print "$base64";
```

The error coming on running it is `RSA.xs:178: OpenSSL error: unsupported encryption at test.pl line 7.`

NOTE: As discussed in the comments, I am using a passphrase protected `id_rsa`.

Comment: The lack of any code will make people less inclined to answer your question. I suggest you show your best effort from these days of work, and describe the problem you are having.

Comment: I have put my code i hope it will help.

Comment: The point is now i am in a dilemma that is this even possible to use SSH private key for signing data in perl because nowhere i am able to find one single example of this happening and all the modules are generating there own private key and have no mention of using ssh private key for signing.

Comment: It is a public private key pair, and therefore -should- be possible. But it might be a bit more complicated, as the format of the key file may not match what openSSL expects.

Comment: I even tried using Crypt::RSA and i hoped that it might be able to do what i want but there also i hit the wall. I also think that it should be possible but i am not able to find a way to do so and not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: It's definitely possible without perl - just need to check why perl doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, leaving out the perl, and just doing this by hand with openssl

#### Checking the key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f test_id

openssl rsa -in test_id -check
  RSA key ok
```

So we do have a 'valid' RSA private key there, which we should be able to use for encrpyting.

#### Generating a comparison key

However if you use openssl  to generate a key pair

```
openssl genrsa -out openssl_gen_rsa
openssl rsa -in openssl_gen_rsa -pubout -out openssl_gen_rsa.out
```

Looks like the command you need is:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey test_id  -in test_file.txt -encrypt -out test_file.enc
```

(That encrypts with the private key, so you'd decrypt with the public key - that's actually pretty similar to signing - normally you wouldn't do this).

The problem is - if you compare your generated -public- keys they don't match. `test_id.pub` looks like (Yes, this is the real one, and no, I did only use it for testing!)

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDKfjRD+Gb5EE+SgOy7eoT0siQaAqfSY7KI2wkdrdygnJ+ccW/uMCtCVPhpz00u3EW2Gz1WI    DteLKppjvUem1lKb8Tt2EWBQGyFOYKp44r3AJZgTcxLeDdqSUoiPsjWf1aUqy2Z1fBgtG+QOa7bpA8km6CbsORYX/TVg4B6vvdkkH    K8WcmzBBF3rGsTCM3VXPp56bPoMCbwCsXvIjejmq+JdGHyxUmCxe1PrPyvmoYX3OUqpFBYIjeLWGDI9EXS6jA/r7viIAxdllvulPg    IJ+4mdYzKN+T1ME0X0c+ZdFTMdeUnB9/TZmJr1j8Q/4SQm+3J9CiwtVXKxdkDsDObkcDp root@raspberrypi
```

Where my generated key file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDG8i33AuEp1wqbJgkEsnOmQim3
QT76B/oxsVGfJEDX3h4A6CD+ypBbfhhIn0GlfHanYvcGlpOJIlk3fzspbZNeoPJS
T4a0zQ0z8uJkugl8utyl9WR4tpgBRmzXZ42T/f4QSNqjDxUidRp5zPnXs9aRDtWb
XptswiGL3eVHMpbSnwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I can use my generated pair (encrypting using public key, decrypting using private):

```
openssl rsautl -inkey openssl_gen_rsa.out -pubin  -in test_file.txt -encrypt -out test_file.enc2
openssl rsautl -inkey openssl_gen_rsa -in test_file.enc2 -decrypt
```

This works.

#### Turning your OpenSSH private key into an RSA public key

So if we run your ssh private key through openssl:

```
openssl rsa -in test_id -pubout -out test_id.openssl.pub
```

We get:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyn40Q/hm+RBPkoDsu3qE
9LIkGgKn0mOyiNsJHa3coJyfnHFv7jArQlT4ac9NLtxFths9ViA7XiyqaY71HptZ
Sm/E7dhFgUBshTmCqeOK9wCWYE3MS3g3aklKIj7I1n9WlKstmdXwYLRvkDmu26QP
JJugm7DkWF/01YOAer73ZJByvFnJswQRd6xrEwjN1Vz6eemz6DAm8ArF7yI3o5qv
iXRh8sVJgsXtT6z8r5qGF9zlKqRQWCI3i1hgyPRF0uowP6+74iAMXZZb7pT4CCfu
JnWMyjfk9TBNF9HPmXRUzHXlJwff02Zia9Y/EP+EkJvtyfQosLVVysXZA7Azm5HA
6QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Which isn't even a remotely similar encoding to the id_rsa.pub file - and I think therefore why you have this problem.

```
 openssl rsautl -inkey test_id.openssl.pub -pubin  -in test_file.txt -encrypt -out test_file.openssl.pub.enc
```

Now works, and you can decrypt it using your `test_id` private key:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey test_id -in test_file.openssl.pub.enc -decrypt
```

So yes - for some reason the public key generated by ssh-keygen isn't the same format as openssl is expecting, so it's not going to work.

#### using an openssh key to verify

Anyway, back to your original example - using the private key to generate a signature:

```
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey test_id -in test_file.txt -out test_file.sig
openssl rsautl -verify -in test_file.sig -inkey test_id.openssl.pub -pubin
```

But the verify step *won't* work using the generated ssh key.

So does this answer your question as to whether it's `possible`? I'm afraid I don't know how the ssh public key differs from a 'normal' rsa public key.

I suspect your code therefore doesn't even need to be as complicated as it - I don't think you need to pkcs pad your key file.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp   qw(read_file);
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 encode_base64 );

my $keystring = read_file ('test_id');
my $privatekey = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($keystring);
my $datatosign = "hello";
my $signature = $privatekey->sign($datatosign);
my $base64 = encode_base64($signature);
print "Signature:\n";
print "$base64";

my $public_key_text = $privatekey-> get_public_key_string();
print "Public Key:\n";
print $public_key_text;

my $rsa_pub = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key ( $public_key_text );
print "Signed correctly\n" if ($rsa_pub->verify($datatosign, decode_base64($base64)));
```

This seems to work. (note lack of pkcs padding line).

#### Encrypted private key (passphrase)

Following from comments:

If your `id_rsa` has a passphrase set you'll have something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,B44716076DD8B7D2B5E909BB8F70B48B
```

You can decrypt this by hand using openssl again:

```
openssl rsa -in test_id.enc
Enter pass phrase for test_id.enc:
```

Or:

```
openssl rsa -in test_id.enc -passin pass:testpass
```

I'm less sure how you do this using `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA` - there doesn't seem to be any option to specify a passphrase to a private key.

I think you therefore need to use `Crypt::CBC` to decrypt the private key first. I can't test this, because I've got a load of dependencies to install.

A bit of googling suggests that you might be able to use [`Crypt::PK::RSA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PK::RSA) instead.

And as an alernative - use `IPC::Open2` and start an `openssl` process to do the things without using libraries at all.

e.g.

```
my $keystring = `openssl rsa -passin pass:testpass -in test_id.enc`;
```

Not very nice, but it'll work. (and test it does actually work)

Comment: even after removing the padding the code is not working at all to signing. The condition with me is to do it in perl and do so using the ssh keys and i am not able to work around this problem.sudo

Comment: I do not know if this might be of help but someone suggest to convert the key into `DER` format. So i run `openssl rsa -outform DER < id_rsa >privkey` and then use `privkey` as file to read from. Now there is a new error coming which is `RSA.xs:178: OpenSSL error: no start line at test.pl line 7`

Comment: OK - just added some code that I've checked works. Converting to DER wasn't necessary, but generating a different public key file was.

Comment: I suppose you did not use the passphrase while creating test_id because it is working fine without passphrase but with it giving error of `unsupported encryption`.

Comment: OK. That's before you even start with openssl - reading the file is giving you ciphertext, which you'll have to decrypt before you  can use it.

Comment: I am not able to get what you are saying. I think that `my $privatekey = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($keystring);` is giving error because OpenSSL is not able to create private key from the $keystring which basically is SSH private key.

Comment: If you've a passphrase set, then your private key is encrypted. Therefore you can't just use it as an RSA private key without decrypting it first. `openssl rsa -in keyfile` will - after you specify the passphrase - spit out an unencrypted private key. You need to do the equivalent of this - in perl - before you can do the rest. I _think_ that means using `Crypt::CBC` to decrypt the private key first.

Comment: Okk i get your point and will look into it. By look it seem that it might solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Before going too far - why not try just: `my $keystring = `openssl rsa -passin pass:testpass -in test_id.enc`;` 

And see if the rest works ok?

Comment: Thanks it is working now using `my $keystring = openssl rsa -passin pass:testpass -in test_id.enc;`. Thanks a lot :):):):)

Comment: That's bypassing the SSL module - I'd be tempted to not mix and match and just do the whole lot through 'openssl' directly. You may want to double check what appears in `ps` as well - just to see if your password shows up.

Comment: yeah i can do all with openssl directly or what i can do is to look for some perl module which can help me in decrypting private key file. I hope both ways can lead to the goal.